# How to check if some packages can be removed

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I want to minimize my Ubuntu system, which means that I'm trying to remove the installed packages by default as many as I can.

My goal is to get a minimized Ubuntu system so that I can run my own cpp project (of course I will install cmake, gcc on my own).

For now, my method is to use `apt` or `dpkg` to list all packages installed, then to remove one package from the list and reboot, if the system can be rebooted normally, I'm gonna say that the package can be removed.

As you see, this method is very bad because it takes so much time.

I just want to know if there is some better way to do so.

Comment: You should do it the other way around: start from `ubuntu-minimal` and install only those things you need.

Comment: @muru It seems that it needs the Internet to install `ubuntu-minimal`, right? My environment has no Internet, I have to install some ubuntu system with `iso`.

Comment: You can't setup a VM for testing? After all, you do have internet to get the ISO.

Comment: Being able to boot does not prove that the system will do everything you want it to do.

Comment: @muclux  Could you explain more? For now my need is to minimize the system and execute my own cpp project. So IMHO, to compile and execute the cpp project, I can install `cmake`, `gcc` on my own.

Comment: You can at each step remove half of the suspected packages. In 10 steps, you can make 1024 distinctions. (2^10).

Comment: I'm not sure how removing packages will help, but the `--dry-run` option to `apt-get` will show what is going to be removed.